# Javascript method not defined

Tags: javascript, methods

Why does this not work when I move the code in the first script block (without the script tag itself) to an external javascript file.

The idea is to call homead.load() from home page and load everything processed by homead_build();

Error says **'homead not defined**' using Firefox Error console

```
<div id="box">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var homead = {
        box_id: "box",
        width: "150px",
        load: function(){
        homead.homead_build();
        },

        homead_build: function(){
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.style.width = homead.width;
            div.style.height = '55px';
            div.style.border = 'solid 2px #000';
            var box = document.getElementById(homead.box_id);
            box.appendChild(div);
        }
    };
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

   homead.load();
</script>
```

Comment: Check to see your javascript external file is being loaded. Fiddler is a very handy tool for this.

Comment: What does your external file look like? (I realize it's *mostly* like the code quoted above, but *mostly* is a tricky concept.) What does your `script` tag for loading it look like? Because what you describe above should work. Separately: Note that it's important that you make sure you include the second bit *below* your `box` element on the page...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are including the external script file after you call `homead.load()`? Make sure it is loaded before it is used:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

   homead.load();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include it before using homead, and that the file has been loaded correctly.
(e.g.: say alert("im loaded...") in the file)

Your code can be simplified btw:

```
var homead = {
    box_id: "box",
    width: "150px",
    load: function(){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = homead.width;
        div.style.height = '55px';
        div.style.border = 'solid 2px #000';
        var box = document.getElementById(homead.box_id);
        box.appendChild(div);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

yes its working fine.You might be giving wrong src path of file to script tag.

I have done following ;

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/test.js" ></script>
```

added code

```
    <div id="box">
</div>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

   homead.load();
</script>
```